# How do I retrieve a value from a PHP array?

Tags: php

How do I retrieve an `integer value` from a PHP array so that I can use it in another function to fetch the details based on that `integer value`(primary key)?

*This is what I get when I print the array:*

```
print_r($myarray);
```

*result:*

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
   (
     [id] => 21785
     [customer_id] => 12456 //this is my primary key
     [date] => 12-06-2017         
   )
)

//I am trying to retrieve the ID using something like the code below:

$cust_id = var_dump($myarray[0]['customer_id']);

 return cust_id;
 or   
 myfunc(cust_id);
```

My problem is that it's not returning the customer_id integer into `$cust_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `var_dump` function doesn't *return* anything.  It prints to the output, but that doesn't matter to the variable.

What you want is to simply access the value directly and store it in the variable.  No function required:

```
$cust_id = $myarray[0]['customer_id'];
```